# Powershell script to get audio tracklist timestamps sequentially

Tags: powershell, audio, timestamp

I am a noob at Powershell. I was trying to make an audiotracklist with timestamps.
The code I need is one that would read a text file containing mp3 locations and the program would get the timestamps, for eg:
Consider a file.txt with following text:

C:\Folder\Song1.mp3
C:\Folder\Song1.mp3
C:\Folder\Song1.mp3

The program should print the following in timestamp.txt as:
00:00:00 - 00:02:30 - Song1.mp3
00:02:30 - 00:04:32 - Song2.mp3
00:04:32 - 00:07:30 - Song3.mp3

I tried the following code

```
$path = 'C:\Sanal\Gambit\mp3\'

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.mp3 -name | Foreach-Object {
    $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
    $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($path)
    $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_)

    write-host  $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27) $_;
}
```

Which just gives the end time of each mp3 file without adding them sequentially.
Can someone please help me with creating a program for my needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you was near :)

```
$path = 'C:\Sanal\Gambit\mp3\'

Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.mp3 -name | Foreach-Object `
   -Begin {
      [timespan]$startTime = [timespan]::Zero
      [timespan]$fullTime = [timespan]::Zero
      $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
      $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($path)
   } `
   -Process {
      $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_)

      $startTime = $fullTime
      $fullTime += $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)
      "$startTime - $fullTime - $_"
   }
```

Declaring `$shell` and `$shellfolder` in the `Begin` block is more optimized since they are not defined on each file (which is useless).

Unless you explicitly want to display it on the console, you should avoid `Write-Host` because it consumes the pipeline, so if you want to store the result in a file, your file will be empty.
With `"$startTime - $fullTime - $_"` it will output if there is no pipeline, and be passed to the pipeline if there is one .

You can add after the closing curly bracket (`}`) of the `Process` block  `| Out-File myResult.txt` to store it in a file, or  `| Tee-Object myResult.txt` if you want both display it and save it.

Edit:

If you want to get it from a list which contains only folders :

```
Get-Content list.txt |
    ForEach {
        $path = $_
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Filter *.mp3 -Name | Foreach-Object `
            -Begin {
                [timespan]$startTime = [timespan]::Zero
                [timespan]$fullTime = [timespan]::Zero
                $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
                $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($path)
            } `
            -Process {
                $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_)

                $startTime = $fullTime
                $duration = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)
                $fullTime += $duration
                #"$startTime - $fullTime - $path\$_"
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Path=$path;
                    FileName=$_;
                    Duration=$duration;
                    StartTime=$startTime;
                    EndTime=$fullTime
                }
            }
    }
```

as suggested by @iRon, I have commented `"$startTime - $fullTime - $path\$_"` and return a PSCustomObject, you can remove it if you prefer the first way (in this case, do not forget to comment out the previous line)

Timestamps are reseted for each folder, if you prefer to have an overall timestamp, move the lines

```
[timespan]$startTime = [timespan]::Zero
[timespan]$fullTime = [timespan]::Zero
```

and put them at the beginning of the script (above `Get-Content ...`), just like in the second edit.

Second edit :

and if you want to get it from a list which contains folders and files :

```
[timespan]$startTime = [timespan]::Zero
[timespan]$fullTime = [timespan]::Zero
Get-Content list.txt |
    ForEach {
        $path = $_
        $file = ""
        if ($_ -match "\.mp3$")
        {
            $path = $_.SubString(0, $_.LastIndexOf('\'))
            $file = $_.SubString($_.LastIndexOf('\') + 1)
        }
        Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$path\$file" -Filter *.mp3 -Name | Foreach-Object `
            -Begin {
                $shell = New-Object -COMObject Shell.Application
                $shellfolder = $shell.Namespace($path)
            } `
            -Process {
                $shellfile = $shellfolder.ParseName($_)

                $startTime = $fullTime
                $duration = $shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)
                $fullTime += $duration
                #"$startTime - $fullTime - $path\$_"
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Path=$path;
                    FileName=$_;
                    Duration=$duration;
                    StartTime=$startTime;
                    EndTime=$fullTime
                }
            }
    }
```

In this case, only an overall timestamp seems appropriate.

Comment: is it possible to make this script read a text file for specific mp3 files location and then as per location add timestamps sequentially for the specified files only??

Comment: see my edit, and if it is good for you don't forget to mark it as answered ;)

Comment: i just found a difficulty, both the scripts that you provided end up sorting the output in alphabetical order whereas my tracklist is not in alphabetic order... can you help me with that so that the timestamps are not in alphabetical order and rather in the order it's specified in list?

Comment: Your list contains folders or files ? I have just tested it with unordered folders, and it returns the values in the same order. Since my mp3 all start with `01 -` , `02 -` ... my files are ordered, but within the folder. Each folder is correctly evaluated in the list order

Comment: my text file has the folder locations, but the mp3 files aren't in alphabetical order in the text, but the program prints out the output in alphabetical order. I wanted the output to be in the order in which it was in the text file; for eg: the file has c.mp3,d.mp3,b.mp3,a.mp3.... i want the output to be in c,d,b,a order and not in a,b,c,d order which the program currently is doing

Comment: So, your file contains files, and not only folders, see my second edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it worked perfectly... I did a small change and added " write-host $startTime : $fullTime - $_  " before the PSCustomObject and commented the rest below. Once again, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) (which outputs the results to the display and should generally be avoided), you better put a string (or a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject)) in the pipeline, which could be easily sorted:

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Filter *.mp3 -name | Foreach-Object {
    ...
    "$($shellfolder.GetDetailsOf($shellfile, 27)) $_"
} | Sort-Object
```

Comment: I had leave the page open for a while, so when i finally answered, I see yours :) We are agree for Write-Host ;) but @BitBit will not have an incrementation for the timestamps